# How can I do variable substitution in this putty plink echo command

Tags: putty, plink

I'm trying to break down the following plink command and modify it to allow a variable substitution.

`plink.exe 192.168.1.1 --% echo """#define MYSPACE""" > /home/my/file.txt`

I want to do the following, but But what follows the `echo` is sent to bash verbatim.

`plink.exe 192.168.1.1 --% echo """#define MYSPACE""" > /$(home)/my/file.txt`

Constructing the `echo` string before the `plink` command doesn't work for the same reason; everything after `echo` is sent verbatim. How can this be done?

Comment: Welcome!  For your putty connection, what is the shell you are using?  That will affect exactly how quoting and variable substitution behave.

Comment: Windows PowerShell to bash

Comment: Where do you want the variable substitution to occur?  In PowerShell, or in bash?

Comment: Substitution in locally in PowerShell; file created remotely by bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the PowerShell side, if `home` is a defined environment variable, that will still be expanded after the `--%`.  So,

`plink.exe 192.168.1.1 --% echo """#define MYSPACE""" > /%home%/my/file.txt`

For additional information on how the `--%` works, see ["the stop parsing token" at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token)

Answer (score 0):

For variable expansion on the bash side, your variable substitution syntax is slightly off.

Most shells want the variable name surrounded by curly braces - `{ }`.  But it looks like you are using parentheses.  In bash, that `$(...)` construct will try to run a subshell, and you'll get very odd errors.

So, try
`plink.exe 192.168.1.1 --% echo """#define MYSPACE""" > /${home}/my/file.txt`

Comment: Clarification - I want the variable substitution to happen in PowerShell before the command is sent. So far I can't get PS to do any subst after the --%. I can subst before the --%; i.e. plink.exe $ip_addr. Whether I use $(var) or ${var}, I get an invalid subst error from bash because it doesn't know what to do with ${var}

Comment: That's the very point of the `--%`.

Comment: Ah, I should have asked what the --% was for; I couldn't find it in a gsearch; I'll remove and try a couple of other things; report back

Comment: @GlenG  Some Microsoft documentation on `--%` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#the-stop-parsing-token